# Error Provider is not clearing itself even if the inputs are valid

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, validation, errorprovider

I am using Windows Forms and Error Provider to validate my Textbox, the validation works as it intended but even if the input matches the validation, the Error Provider wont clear itself.

Here are some screenshots on the issue.

[image: The error provider shows the error correctly]

[image: But when i enter the valid input, the error icon wont disappear.]

Here is my code, please advice me on how to fix it.

```
private void usernamet_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        int username = usernamet.Text.Length;

        ErrorProvider errorProvider = new ErrorProvider();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(usernamet.Text))
        {
            
            e.Cancel = true;
            usernamet.Focus();
            errorProvider.SetError(usernamet, "Username cannot be empty");
        }
        else if (username < 5 || username >= 20 )
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            usernamet.Focus();
            errorProvider.SetError(usernamet, "Username must have more than 5 characters and less than 20 characters.");
        }
        else if (!Regex.IsMatch(usernamet.Text, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9@.]*$"))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            usernamet.Focus();
            errorProvider.SetError(usernamet, "Username cannot contain special characters.");
        }
        else
        {
            e.Cancel = false;
            errorProvider.Clear();
            errorProvider.SetError(usernamet, null);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't do this: `ErrorProvider errorProvider = new ErrorProvider();`. In the designer, drop an ErrorProvider instance from the ToolBox and use it in your code. In the `Validating` event use the `.SetError` method either to set or clear the error for that control.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.clear?view=netframework-4.7.2

Calling this method clears all property settings for this ErrorProvider, restoring the properties to their default values. To clear the error message, call the SetError method and pass in Empty for the String value. This removes the error glyph from the specified Control.

Comment: else
        {
            e.Cancel = false;
            errorProvider.Clear();
            errorProvider.SetError(usernamet, null);
        }

I did passed the null value into the SetError method, but it didnt work as it is intended.

Comment: look at this sample you shouldn't pass null to set error you should pass "" to  it.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-error-provider-control-in-windows-forms-and-C-Sharp/

Comment: else
            {
                e.Cancel = false;
                errorProvider.Clear();
                errorProvider.SetError(usernamet, "");
            }

I passed in the empty string and tested, but the ErrorProvider icon is still not clearing itself, is the issue lies in visual studio instead of the code?

Comment: use this code . usernamet.setErrorEnabled(false);

Comment: It does not work too, i will try to figure it out. Thank you for your help

Comment: well another way you can try maybe it's help you